# How to create animation in html css and js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic-html

Hey am a new developer and am trying to build a website. The main goal of website is to provide a piece of text to the visitors. Some of my helpers gave me a javascript to copy the text inside a `<p></p>` element and it gives a custom alert that the text is copied. But I needed a animation/transition that when I click the copy button the custom copy alert should come from left to right.

```js
 var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('copystatus');

for (let button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
     let statusElement = this.closest('.latestatus');
     let textToCopy = statusElement.getElementsByClassName('copytxt')[0].innerHTML;

    copyTextToClipboard(textToCopy);
    addCopyStatusAlert(this.parentNode);
  });
}

function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  const copyText = document.createElement('textarea');
  copyText.style.position="absolute";
  copyText.style.display="none";
  copyText.value = text;

  document.body.appendChild(copyText);
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(copyText);
}

function addCopyStatusAlert(element) {
  if (!element.getElementsByClassName('status-copy-alert').length) {
    let copyAlertElement = document.createElement('span');
    copyAlertElement.classList.add('status-copy-alert')
    let copyMessage = document.createTextNode('Copied!');
    copyAlertElement.appendChild(copyMessage);

    element.appendChild(copyAlertElement);
    setTimeout(function() {
      element.removeChild(copyAlertElement);
    }, 700);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="mainStatus">
   <h2 class="statusHeading">Latest English Status</h2>
   <div class="allStatus">
    <div class="bock">
     <div class="latestatus">
      <p class="copytxt">Life is good when you have books</p>
      <div>
       <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="latestatus">
      <p class="copytxt">Google is an open source library by Larry Page and Sergey Brin!</p>
      <div>
       <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
     <div class="latestatus">
      <p class="copytxt">Cats are better than dogs.</p>
      <div>
       <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="latestatus">
      <p class="copytxt">Cats are better than dogs.</p>
      <div>
       <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Custom alert is the `<span>` created by JavaScript.
Than in advance

Comment: You probably need CSS's transition on transform translateX, but it's impossible to say exactly as you have not included the CSS for the span element in your question so we don't know where it is/where it has to get to.

Comment: You can also check https://animate.style/ if you want css library.

Comment: status-copy-alert {
 position: relative;
 background-color: #18b495;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 10px 10px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 left: 8px;
}
.status-copy-alert:before{
 content:"";
 position: absolute;
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #18b495;
 left: -5px;
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 top: 39%;
}

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @A Haworth in comments below is the code snippet that uses css [transformation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).
I've updated timeout from 700 to 800 to make the span stay little longer.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('copystatus');

for (let button of buttons) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let statusElement = this.closest('.latestatus');
    let textToCopy = statusElement.getElementsByClassName('copytxt')[0].innerHTML;

    copyTextToClipboard(textToCopy);
    addCopyStatusAlert(this.parentNode);
  });
}

function copyTextToClipboard(text) {
  const copyText = document.createElement('textarea');
  copyText.style.position = "absolute";
  copyText.style.display = "none";
  copyText.value = text;

  document.body.appendChild(copyText);
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(copyText);
}

function addCopyStatusAlert(element) {
  if (!element.getElementsByClassName('status-copy-alert').length) {
    let copyAlertElement = document.createElement('span');
    let copyMessage = document.createTextNode('Copied!');
    copyAlertElement.appendChild(copyMessage);

    element.appendChild(copyAlertElement);
    copyAlertElement.classList.add('status-copy-alert', 'slide-in');
    setTimeout(function() {
      element.removeChild(copyAlertElement);
    }, 800);
  }
}
```

```css
.slide-in {
  animation: slide-in 0.25s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in 0.25s forwards;
}

@keyframes slide-in {
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-in {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

.status-copy-alert {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #18b495;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 65px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.status-copy-alert:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #18b495;
  left: -5px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 39%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="mainStatus">
  <h2 class="statusHeading">Latest English Status</h2>
  <div class="allStatus">
    <div class="bock">
      <div class="latestatus">
        <p class="copytxt">Life is good when you have books</p>
        <div>
          <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="latestatus">
        <p class="copytxt">Google is an open source library by Larry Page and Sergey Brin!</p>
        <div>
          <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="latestatus">
        <p class="copytxt">Cats are better than dogs.</p>
        <div>
          <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="latestatus">
        <p class="copytxt">Cats are better than dogs.</p>
        <div>
          <button class="copystatus btn">Copy</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what exactly is not working?